# CSRF protection in web application

Tags: java, spring, apache, csrf

I have application that have **CSRF protection** provided by apache modules. My application containt a few pages that allow to upload some files, looks like this:

```
<form:form method="post" action="my.controller" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
```

All stuff worked fine by the time we have updated our apache version from  **`httpd-2.2.3`** to **`httpd-2.2.15`**.

I've googled some time, and found that issue can be related to **multipart/form-data** parameter in the my form. In this case the form send as not secured. Also I've found that spring can handle stuff as above via **`MultipartFilter`** from spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipartfilter

I am new in CSRF stuff. Will be good to know whehter it is possible to use **spring CSRF protection** with **apache** configuration to handle such cases.

Also I've found workaround where I can disable CSRF for needed URLs, like

> RewriteRule /url/mycontroller.controller - [E=CSRF_IGNORE:yes]

But I am not sure wherer it will be correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the suggestions I have:

Please remove the enctype if not required since multipart/form-data is not supported in some of the CSRF libraries including CSRF Guard.

If you are setting the CSRF token using hidden attribute, please try appending the token in the action attribute.
Here is this link : https://code.google.com/p/csrf-filter/

If you still face the same issue, you may have to exclude the URL from CSRF check.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your point regarding google filter. Please explain, in which way it should fix issue with multipart/form-data parameter. Thanks